# "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

ssue with establishing a connection in a browser extension, particularly in the popup.html file. The stack trace points to line 12 in popup.html where an anonymous function is called. Additionally, there is another instance of the error at line 0 in popup.html with an anonymous function.
popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>URL Shortener</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="shortenButton">Shorten URL</button>
    <div id="shortenedUrlContainer" class="messageContainer"></div>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

content.js

```
// content.js
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'content-script' });
port.postMessage({ action: 'shortenUrl', url: 'testurl' });

console.log('Content script is running');
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log('DOM content loaded');

    const shortenButton = document.getElementById("shortenButton");

    if (shortenButton) {
        shortenButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log('Button clicked');
            // Your existing logic here
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "shortenUrl", url: 'testurl' });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Button not found');
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === "shortenUrl") {
        shortenUrl(request.url, function (shortenedUrl, error) {
            if (shortenedUrl) {
                displayMessage('success', 'URL shortened successfully!');
            } else {
                displayMessage('error', 'Error shortening URL. Please try again.');
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    
});

function shortenUrl(url, callback) {
    // The existing shortenUrl logic from shortenUrl.js
    // Make sure to replace the placeholder values in the Bitly API call.

    // ... (same code as in shortenUrl.js)
}



function displayMessage(type, message, shortenedUrl) {
    const messageContainer = document.createElement('div');
    messageContainer.textContent = message;
    messageContainer.className = type;
    messageContainer.style.position = 'fixed';
    messageContainer.style.top = '0';
    messageContainer.style.left = '0';
    messageContainer.style.zIndex = '9999';
    messageContainer.style.backgroundColor = type === 'success' ? 'green' : 'red';
    messageContainer.style.color = 'white';
    messageContainer.style.padding = '10px';

    // If there's a shortened URL, display it in a separate div
    if (shortenedUrl) {
        const urlContainer = document.createElement('div');
        urlContainer.textContent = 'Shortened URL: ' + shortenedUrl;
        urlContainer.style.marginTop = '5px';
        messageContainer.appendChild(urlContainer);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(messageContainer);

    setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(messageContainer);
    }, 3000);
}

function displayShortenedUrl(shortenedUrl) {
    const shortenedUrlContainer = document.getElementById('shortenedUrlContainer');
    if (shortenedUrlContainer) {
        shortenedUrlContainer.textContent = `Shortened URL: ${shortenedUrl}`;
        shortenedUrlContainer.style.display = 'block'; // Show the container
    }
}
```

background.js

```
// background.js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
  });
  
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    console.assert(port.name === 'content-script');
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        if (msg.action === 'shortenUrl') {
            // Your existing logic here
        }
    });
});

console.log('Background script is running');

function shortenUrl(url, callback) {
    const accessToken = '.....'; // 
    const apiUrl = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten';

    fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            long_url: url,
            group_guid: 'YOUR_BITLY_GROUP_GUID' // Replace with your Bitly group GUID if applicable
        })
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        const shortenedUrl = data.id;
        callback(shortenedUrl, null);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error shortening URL:', error.message);
        callback(null, error.message); // Pass error message to the callback
    });
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === "shortenUrl") {
        shortenUrl(request.url, function (shortenedUrl, error) {
            if (shortenedUrl) {
                copyToClipboard(shortenedUrl);
                // Pass the shortened URL to the displayMessage function
                displayMessage('success', 'URL shortened successfully!', shortenedUrl);
            } else {
                const errorMessage = error ? `Error: ${error}` : 'Error shortening URL. Please try again.';
                // Pass null as the shortened URL to the displayMessage function
                displayMessage('error', errorMessage, null);
            }
        });
        // Return true to indicate that the sendResponse callback will be called asynchronously
        return true;
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "URL Shortener",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Shortens the current webpage URL and copies it to the clipboard.",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "clipboardWrite"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon":  "./icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have tried to turn off all other extensions, reload the chrome but the same issues persist.

Comment: You can't load background.js or content.js in the popup. These two scripts are for a completely separate context. Judging by the posted code you should remove `content_scripts` from manifest.json, rename content.js to popup.js, remove background.js, remove all messaging, and simply call `fetch` directly in popup.js.

Comment: @wOxxOm, i tried as you advised but still did not work. So I changed the design in hopes of any changes in errors.

Comment: You need to add `host_permissions` for your API server. Also debug to find out what exactly doesn't work. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.